# Is there a way of using XNA+Xbox 360 with the current generation of 3D televisions?

Tags: xna, 3d, xbox360

I'm interested in playing around with 3D on a new Sony 3D television (polarized light rather than red/green/blue anaglyph glasses).  Is this possible with XNA on the current XBox 360?

Alternatively, It doesn't look like there is a comparatively trivial PS3 dev. solution to XNA right now, hence my interest in XNA and the 360.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Check if you can manually set your 3D TV to the type of 3D input it's receiving. A quick look at one Sony 3D TV manual showed it could be manually set to generate the 3D image from either side-by-side or over-under images, where the content for the two eyes are provided in one extra wide or extra tall image.

It's possible if you can create a frontbuffer of the right size then you can just render two images in this way and set your TV to look for it (seem to recall this might be how Avatar the game did it on the 360). Your content would then potentially be rendered correctly, but the 360 guide or pop-ups that get overlaid by the system would be displayed incorrectly until XNA officially supported 3D.

Comment: I think that the 360 guide would be displayed just fine.

Comment: @Olhovsky If you've got one buffer that contains two images and the system has no concept of this, then when it tries to display the system HUD in the centre of what it thinks is the screen (or any notification could potentially just be rendered into the left or right image) will actually have it half span the left and the right eye images and look incorrect. XNA would need to have an understanding of 3D itself and notify the system this is what it was doing (which would most likely also be able to tell the TV to switch to the right mode automatically)

Comment: @Roger Perkins I thought that 3D TV's using polarized light render the left image, then the right, meaning you have to run at 120 FPS to keep a smooth image. In the case of side-by-side rendering, if the X360 doesn't take this into account, the image should be split up and not shown corrently at all?

Comment: I wont have access to the TV for a couple of weeks yet (am currently abroad).  I'll come back to this thread and report when I get a chance to try what has been discussed.

Comment: @3nixios They may well display like that for the glasses, but the HDMI 1.4 format specification specifies that displays need to support a range of input formats, including frame packing. The television could take a 60hz packed image then display the alternate left/right images at 120hz to allow it to show both eyes separately.

Comment: @Roger Perkins: You're right about the guide display. I didn't consider that.